# How do I use SQL IN statement of string values for int column?

Tags: sql-server-2008

For circumstances out of my hand, I have a string of values:

```
@param1 = "1,2,3,4";
```

How do I do IN statement to check if an ID is in my string @param1?

so, it would look something like this:

```
select * from table1 where ID IN (@param1);
```

Normally, I guess I should have this:

```
select * from table1 where ID IN (1,2,3,4);
```

But unfortunately, under my circumstances, I simply don't have that, instead, I have just one parameter of type string of all my IDs concatenated, how do I select the rows from that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613273/sql-use-comma-separated-values-with-in-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dynamically-generated SQL statement ([**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f7a3/4)):

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = 'select * from table1 where ID IN (' + @param1 + ')'
exec(@sql)
```

The idea is to build a SQL statement in a string variable by concatenating the ID list into a SQL statement.  The final statement looks like your expected query:

```
select * from table1 where ID IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Then you can run the contents of the string variable as a SQL command using [`exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx).

Comment: My query is really really long... is there anyway you can separate the @param1 dynamic query into it's own query?